# Alt Tab for all workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I thought Alt + Tab would cycle though all open programs that are in different workspaces.  I think this should be dynamic according to if you have workspace toggle on or off. I know this can be done with ccsm, but I like keep my systems with minimal tweaks as that makes the dist-upgrade process a smooth transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`unity-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) instead:

[image: Go to 'Switcher', looking options under 'Unity', and look for 'Switch between windows on all workspaces', and enable it.]

Comment: Thank you, I did this just this morning and works like a charm.

Comment: If it works, you might want to mark it as answered :)